How to work angular material table responsive in Angular v17
So I've been following these process that help how to set angular material table responsive:material-table. I'm trying to use this one on my local: stackblizAngular12+.
I modify multiple times the at-table-responsive.directive.scss but nothing seems to work. Although, the directive.ts its seem to work fine. I try to use other examples that is provided there also with angular 17 ts strictmode and got same result. My guess will be on package json and tsconfig but I'm still learning from those files. Does Anyone have encounter this? I'm running on Angular 17

please provide minimal reproducible code!

Check this : https://therichpost.com/angular-17-material-data-table-with-custom-button-click-event-functionality-working-demo/

This is the work around I found...
.table-responsive {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   min-height: auto;
   max-height: calc(100vh - 25rem);
}

This class can help you out with the responsiveness of the table like below...
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table>
   ...
   </table>
</div>

This will work with material also, you don't have to put any extra efforts to find it in angular docs.
